# Updated How to secure electric mast to wooden siding

Tags: electrical, conduit, siding

I need to secure a 10 feet service mast that will past through the roof on the outside. From grade to top of roof is just over 10 feet. Utilities company has stipulated that the mast must be at least 14 ft high from the ground. I have overlapping wood sidings so the surface is not flat (see updated photo).

Second photo shows the PGE's utilities spotting. The service line is surprisingly well clear of trees, considering it is OR, so I might be able to get away without guide wires if I keep the total mast height below 24 inches. Concrete tiled roofs make for extra work! The service feed line comes in from the left frame of the photo.

Two concern with using Kinkorf straps:

1. The overlapping siding is not a flat surface. Mounting the channel tube on it would result in about a 10-15 degree tilt.
2. The service line will be pulling from the left and the channel tubes also run left-right.

I can locate the studs, figuring that I can secure the Kindorf rails directly to them. This would avoid tearing out the wall panels on inside. Would these factors still result in a stable mounting using Kinkorf bracing? A second related question is, can I use the Kindorf braces to secure the meter socket? PGE's handbook says that the meter support backing should be a 2x4.

Thanks[image: !]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCb7d.png)

[image]

Comment: How about a picture of where you actually have to attach the mast and the meter can.

Comment: What do you mean the bar will be at an angle?

Comment: @JACK Photo added.

Comment: @Ed Beal Siding would make the Kindorf rails tilt at about 10-15 degrees from the parallel mast.

Answer (score 0):

I do use strut channel and straps Kindof is one brand, uni strut, super strut are others that may be less expensive, I believe I usually use 3/4” steel and cut each piece 18”-20” long or what is needed to span 2 studs then lag into a stud on each side.

at 14’ (quite normal) you will have enough above the roof to justify a guy wire in the direction opposite the pole.

I do this quite often in Oregon as it is common to have a tree limb take out a feeder a little extra protection now may pay off and break the guy wire & splices verses tearing up the roof and mast.

It may be required depending on your wall and foundation heights but thought it should be mentioned.

Comment: Yes. I was planning on spanning the 16" studs too. That would provide better than the 2x4 back support that PGE stipulates. I am using Kindorf like Hoover is for vacuum cleaners. So having the Kindorf rails at a slight angle does not affect the stability, bear in mind that the feed line coming from the side.?